# When should I use GWT widget (explication)?

Tags: gwt, optimization, widget

I am doing a GWT application and speed tracer says that the painting process take a long time, so reading the pdf of the : Google 2010 - IO session ("Architecting for performance with GWT"), this sentence appear :

> When should I use widgets?
>   When a component must receive events AND
>   There's no way to catch events in the parent widget

I agree with the first condition (I want to use widgets because my component, such as textBox or images must receive events, such as MouseOver, MouseClick...) but my question concern the second condition. Indeed I do not understand **in which case** there should be **no way** to catch event in the parent widget since it is ("always") possible to access to any element/component manipulating the DOM with Javascript. Here I am supposing that with Javascript I can access to the Widgets (identified with ui:field for example in ui:binder) element and the DOM elements (identified with id="").

So could you tell me why I am wrong or give me an example when "There's no way to catch events in the parent widget" ?

Thanks you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more about "no *easy* way to put code that would catch events in the parent widget". It's all about componentization: you don't want to put event handling code outside your component, and you don't want to make your event handling code attach to elements outside your component. So components still are widgets, but inside them try to use HTML and event bubbling as much as possible.

In practice, that means using `HTMLPanel` (or `RenderablePanel` for better perfs, if you use 2.5.0 RC1 and you're a bit adventurous) inside composites, and otherwise using `CellWidget` (with [`UiRenderer`](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder#Rendering_HTML_for_Cells) to make it way easy to handle events bubbling from specific child elements)